# Vue slot not working - child elements show as empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, vuejs-slots

I have the following code where I am trying to pass individual tab components into a tabs component via `slots`. However, the tabs do not seem to be getting passed. Putting `{{ tabs }}` on the template only shows an empty array.

```
<template>
  <article>
    {{ tabs }} // empty array
    <header class="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
          <div class="nav-item"
              :class="{ 'is-active': tab.isActive }"
              @click="selectTab(tab)">
            {{ tab.name }}
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <section class="tabs-details">
      <slot></slot>
    </section>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => {
      return {
        tabs: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      selectTab(selectedTab) {
        this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
          tab.isActive = tab.name === selectedTab.name;
        });
      }
    },
    created() {
      console.log('created[Tabs.vue]-> ',  this.$children) // nothing here
      this.tabs = this.$children; // not working
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have my components registered in the parent like so:

```
 import Tab from '@/components/Tab'
 import Tabs from '@/components/Tabs'

  export default {
    components: {
      Datepicker,
      Tab,
      Tabs
    },
...
```

The template is pretty straight forward. Note, the contents of the individual tabs display fine when `selected="true"`

```
  <Tabs>
    <Tab name="hours" selected="true">Contents here...</Tab> 
    <Tab name="pay"></Tab>
  </Tabs>
```

I have checked in the browser console and, although the `nav-item` `<li>` elements are being created, they have no content.

I'm new to slots so maybe I am missing something obvious or the code syntax I am using is outdated. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you working with vue 2 or 3?

Comment: The version is Vue 2.2.3.

Comment: This starts feeling like a XY problem. What are you trying to achieve? I mean functionally. What is the goal of the feature?

Answer (score 1):

[$children](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/children.html#children) has been deprecated in Vue 3:

> In 3.x, the `$children` property is removed and no longer supported. Instead, if you need to access a child component instance, we recommend using [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs).

---

If you're trying to get children of `<slot></slot>`, use `this.$slots.default()`, as suggested in [Boussadjra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73953304/1891677).

---

In Vue2, the syntax for getting the default slot contents is `this.$slots.default` (not a function).
Notes:

- you'll get back an array of `VNode`s, not actual DOM,
- you can only access `$slots` after component has been mounted (e.g: in `mounted()` hook)

If you want specific data from the vNodes, you'll have to log them and see where exactly it is in your version of Vue (vNodes have had minor changes over time - they're considered internal API).

---

My advice would be to upgrade to a newer version of 2. If not `2.7.10`, at least `2.6.14`. Some of the [available documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) on Vue 2 describes features which were not yet added in `2.2.3`. `$slots` had a major revamp in `2.6`.

For example, I was using slots at the time, but if you ask me now how they looked like, I couldn't tell you with certainty.

Comment: I am using Vue 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `this.$slots` :

```js
this.tabs = this.$slots.default();//returns vnodes, that can be rendered via render function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am getting `TypeError: this.$slots.default is not a function`. I assume it's a Vue 2 issue?

Comment: Try it inside the mounted hook

Comment: Is there any other way of getting the child data into the template without needing to resort to `this.$slots.default` and the render function? It seems very cumbersome to simply have the benefit of slots.